# angular translate load json files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I have the following problem regarding page translation using `angular-translate`:

On entry page, the filter shows only ID, but when I click to go other page, it displays the translation.

**My configuration code is:**

```
.config(function ($translateProvider) {

$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
  prefix: 'languages/',
  suffix: '.json'
});
$translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en_US');   
$translateProvider.determinePreferredLanguage();})
```

But, if set the translation json directly in configuration method, it works.

```
.config(function ($translateProvider) {       
$translateProvider.translations('en_US', {
  "USERNAME": "Username",
  "PASSWORD": "Password",
  "JOBS": "Jobs",
  "JOB": "Job",
  "ImageSequenceNumber": "Image Sequence Number",
  "Attach": "Attach",
  "ShareLink": "Share link",
  "HangoutCode": "or hangout code",
  "TakeNewShots": "Take new shots",
  "Shared": "Shared",
  "NoAccountYet": "Don't have account yet?",
  "SignUp": "Sign Up"
});
$translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en_US');
$translateProvider.determinePreferredLanguage();
  })
```

**HTML code:**

```
<input type="text" placeholder = "{{ 'USERNAME' | translate}}" ng-model="data.username">
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: *On entry page, the filter show only ID*: which filter? which ID? which page? What is your code?

Comment: That should be in the question, not in a comment. thetranslate filter uses translate.instant(), which returns what is available **now**. So if the JSON file hasn't been loaded yet, you won't see the translation. Consider not displaying the page content (using ng-if) until you the translations are available (which you can test by using the translate service and wait for the promise to be resolved).

Comment: `$scope.pageCanBeDisplayed = false; $translate('USERNAME').then(function() { $scope.pageCanBeDisplayed = true; });`